# How to add author an affiliation and their email address and all left aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, affiliation

How to add author an affiliation and their email address and all left aligned?

title

author 1, author 2, author 3

Authors affiliation

author1 's email address

abstract

I'm using a single column article document. Title is in center of the page.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single application it's rather pointless defining an appropriate `\maketitle` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\affilmark}[1]{\rlap{\textsuperscript{\itshape#1}}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{3ex}
\begin{center}\LARGE
  The title of this paper, long enough to break over two lines
\end{center}
\vspace*{2ex}
\begin{flushleft}\large
A. N. Author\affilmark{a},\quad
B. P. Another\affilmark{b},\quad
C. Q. Third\affilmark{c}\\[2ex]
\normalsize\itshape
\textsuperscript{a,b}\,Department of Cuisine, University of Nowhere\\
\textsuperscript{c}\,Department of Departmentalization, University of Somewhere\\[1ex]
\upshape Corresponding author's email: \texttt{A.N.Author@nowhere.edu}
\end{flushleft}
\vspace*{3ex}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I would have also the title flush left.

Comment: I compile it the title was at the center.

Comment: first, thank you egreg But my title is big and it does not break how can I break my title. I can't see the beginning part and end part of it.

Comment: @amir: see edit; use the `center` environment instead of `\centerline`. Change the spacings to suit your taste. To flush the title with the left margin, move it into the `flushleft` environment.

Comment: Thank you very much egreg. but when I use `\centerline` instead of `\center` it upsets (disturbs) indentation of my abstract and other section.

Comment: @amir Look at my code: I said the `center` environment, not the `\center` command!

Comment: Sorry for that :). thank you it work out now very well. Best regards.