# How to enter address and email in the following form

Tags: addresses

How to do I enter address and email as in the below format (with the address in all caps and email in italics and in some other font)? I am using LaTeX.

HOME ADDRESS
E-mail address: emailaddy@someschool.edu

Go to the last page here ( page 30 http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.5714.pdf ) to see what I mean. tex.stackexchange won't let me post images until I earn at least 10 points.

So I apologize for the inconvenience.

And thanks for your time.

Comment: That's obtained automatically if you use the `amsart` class. See the documentation: `texdoc amsart`

Comment: I'm sort of new to tex so I learn better through examples...

Comment: I added a few tex.stackexchange links [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28384/how-to-add-author-an-affiliation-and-their-email-address-and-all-left-aligned] as my favorites but this isn't really what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks egreg. I have googled what you recommended and am looking into amsart and texdoc amsart.

Comment: Thanks again egreg. Got it! There are lots of helpful info online.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a very schematic document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\title{Splitting hairs}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\address{Department of Vague Studies, University of Somewhere}
\email{author@somewhere.xy}

\begin{abstract}
In this paper we will extend our previous technique, making
it possible to split hairs in $2^n$ parts, for arbitrary 
(even fractional)~$n$.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

The text

\end{document}
```

[image]